# How to set nameservers for Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, domain, nameserver, godaddy

I created an instance using the standard Ubuntu 10.04 AMI and installed LAMP.
Then associated an elastic IP with the instance.

Now I want to make it accessible through my domain name; rather than an IP address.
My domain is registered at GoDaddy.

Should I go to Host Summary and add ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com?

another question. It is possible to associate more than one IP to an instance? It seems like I can only do one. When I go to the Host Summary section, I can add more than 10 host IPs, and I'm not sure having only 1 IP is good enough or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Log in to GoDaddy and go the domain manager
2. Click on the domain you want to manage.
3. Find the "DNS Manager" area and click the launch link.
4. Edit the host with @ in it and enter the elastic IP you have then save.

It can take a while for this to be seen everywhere since DNS entries are cached.

As far as multiple IPs to an instance the simple answer is no. However there is a way to make [multiple IPs to a single EC2 instance work by load balancing to ports](http://elwoodicious.com/2009/12/23/using-elb-to-serve-multiple-domains-over-ssl-on-ec2-for-giggles/).

Comment: I can't find the launch link in the DNS Manager area. It says "(Not hosted here)" and there is no link. But I added ns1 and ns2 in the Host Summary area. Will it work? And.. although only one elastic IP can be associated, one should be enough, right?

Comment: That probably means they aren't doing authoritative DNS for your domain. It sounds like you may have fixed that so that link should show up eventually. As long as you don't need SSL for multiple domains on your box one IP will be enough.